# Activate Stacks only for some specific ETW Tasks in a provider?

Tags: windows-8.1, stack-trace, etw, wpr

[Since Windows 7 it is possible to activate callstacks for usermode events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee412263.aspx). This works fine, but sometimes activating stacks for all tasks/Events in a provider is not needed and it would be nice to only activate stacks for some specific Tasks. Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this is possible since Windows 8.1 with the type entry in [_EVENT_FILTER_DESCRIPTOR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363758%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) when it is set to [EVENT_FILTER_TYPE_STACKWALK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363758%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) when you call EnableTraceEx2.

> On Windows 8.1,Windows Server 2012 R2, and later, event payload,
> scope, and stack walk filters can be used by the EnableTraceEx2
> function and the ENABLE_TRACE_PARAMETERS and EVENT_FILTER_DESCRIPTOR
> structures to filter on specific conditions in a logger session.
>
> When stack walking is enabled for a provider, then the stack is
> captured for all the events generated by the provider. Most of the
> time, the user is only interested in stack from only certain number of
> events.
>
> This feature allows enabling or disabling stack walking on a list of
> events. The provided filter includes a EVENT_FILTER_EVENT_ID structure
> that contains an array of event IDs and a Boolean value that indicates
> whether to enable or disable stack capturing for the specified events.
> Each event write call will go through this array quickly to find out
> whether the stack should be captured or not.

With [Windows Performance Recorder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh448205.aspx) it is possible to achieve this in the [WPR Profile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh448210.aspx) with a second [EventCollectorId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh448093.aspx) entry which has an [EventProviders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh448199.aspx) entry where stackwalking is enabled.

In this demo profile, I created one EventProvider (`EventProvider_DotNETRuntime`) for provider `Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntime` without stacks to capture JIT and GC data and an other EventProvider (`EventProvider_DotNETRuntime_Stack`) for provider `Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntime` with stacks to capture stacks for Exceptions and Loader Events.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WindowsPerformanceRecorder Version="1.0" Author="MagicAndre1981" Copyright="MagicAndre1981">
  <Profiles>
    <SystemCollector Id="SystemCollector" Name="NT Kernel Logger">
      <BufferSize Value="1024" />
      <Buffers Value="384" />
    </SystemCollector>
    <EventCollector Id="EventCollector_DotNETRuntime_Session" Name="DotNETRuntime_Session">
      <BufferSize Value="1024" />
      <Buffers Value="128" />
    </EventCollector>
    <EventCollector Id="EventCollector_DotNETRuntime_with_Stack" Name="DotNETRuntime_Session_with_Stack">
      <BufferSize Value="1024" />
      <Buffers Value="128" />
    </EventCollector>
    <SystemProvider Id="SystemProvider">
      <Keywords>
        <Keyword Value="ProcessThread" />       <!--PROC_THREAD-->
        <Keyword Value="Loader" />              <!--LOADER-->
        <Keyword Value="SampledProfile" />      <!--PROFILE-->
        <Keyword Value="Interrupt"/>            <!--INTERRUPT-->
        <Keyword Value="DPC"/>                  <!--DPC-->
        <Keyword Value="ReadyThread" />         <!--Dispatcher-->
        <Keyword Value="CSwitch" />             <!--CSwitch-->
      </Keywords>
      <Stacks>
        <Stack Value="SampledProfile" />        <!--Profile-->
        <Stack Value="CSwitch" />               <!--CSwitch-->
        <Stack Value="ReadyThread" />           <!--ReadyThread-->
        <Stack Value="ImageLoad" />             <!--ImageLoad-->
        <Stack Value="ImageUnload" />           <!--ImageUnload-->
      </Stacks>
    </SystemProvider>
    <EventProvider Id="EventProvider_DotNETRuntime" Name="Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntime" Level="5" Stack="false">
      <Keywords>
        <Keyword Value="0x111" />                       <!--GCKeyword, JitKeyword, JitRundownKeyword, EndRundownKeyword -->
      </Keywords>
    </EventProvider>
    <EventProvider Id="EventProvider_DotNETRuntime_Stack" Name="Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntime" Level="5" Stack="true">
      <Keywords>
        <Keyword Value="0x8008" />                      <!--LoaderKeyword, LoaderRundownKeyword, ExceptionKeyword -->
      </Keywords>
    </EventProvider>
    <EventProvider Id="EventProvider_DotNETRuntimePrivate" Name="763fd754-7086-4dfe-95eb-c01a46faf4ca" Level="5" Stack="false">
      <Keywords>
        <Keyword Value="0xE" />
      </Keywords>
    </EventProvider>
    <EventProvider Id="EventProvider_DotNETRuntimeRundown_CaptureState" Name="Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntimeRundown" Level="5" CaptureStateOnly="true" Stack="false">
      <CaptureStateOnSave>
        <Keyword Value="0x118" />
      </CaptureStateOnSave>
    </EventProvider>
    <Profile Id="DotNetRuntimeProfile.Verbose.File" Name="DotNetRuntimeProfile" Description="DotNetRuntime Profile" LoggingMode="File" DetailLevel="Verbose">
      <Collectors>
        <SystemCollectorId Value="SystemCollector">
          <SystemProviderId Value="SystemProvider" />
        </SystemCollectorId>
        <EventCollectorId Value="EventCollector_DotNETRuntime_Session">
          <EventProviders>
            <EventProviderId Value="EventProvider_DotNETRuntime" />
            <EventProviderId Value="EventProvider_DotNETRuntimePrivate" />
            <EventProviderId Value="EventProvider_DotNETRuntimeRundown_CaptureState" />
          </EventProviders>
        </EventCollectorId>
        <EventCollectorId Value="EventCollector_DotNETRuntime_with_Stack">
          <EventProviders>
            <EventProviderId Value="EventProvider_DotNETRuntime_Stack" />
          </EventProviders>
        </EventCollectorId>
      </Collectors>
    </Profile>
    <Profile Id="DotNetRuntimeProfile.Verbose.Memory" Name="DotNetRuntimeProfile" Description="DotNetRuntime Profile" Base="DotNetRuntimeProfile.Verbose.File" LoggingMode="Memory" DetailLevel="Verbose"/>
  </Profiles>
  <TraceMergeProperties>
    <TraceMergeProperty Id="BaseVerboseTraceMergeProperties" Name="BaseTraceMergeProperties" Base="">
      <CustomEvents>
          <CustomEvent Value="ImageId"/>
          <CustomEvent Value="BuildInfo"/>
          <CustomEvent Value="VolumeMapping"/>
          <CustomEvent Value="EventMetadata"/>
          <CustomEvent Value="PerfTrackMetadata"/>
          <CustomEvent Value="NetworkInterface"/>
        </CustomEvents>
      <FileCompression Value="true" />
     </TraceMergeProperty>
  </TraceMergeProperties>
</WindowsPerformanceRecorder>
```

When you now run Windows Performance Recorder to capture the data:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\wpr.exe" -start  DotNetRuntime.wprp
```

, stop the recording

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\wpr.exe" -stop Result.etl
```

open the trace with [Windows Performance Analyzer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh448170.aspx), [load the debug symbols](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh448108.aspx) you can see the stacks for the Exception data, but not for Jit or GC events:

[image: WPA_dotNetRuntime_Events_some_withStacks]

**Attention.** When you run this under Windows 7 or Windows 8 (Build 9200), the last EventLogger for the provider is used with the specified keywords and stack options. Here you should create 2 WPRP profiles and detect the Windows version and run the correct profile.