# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks, Version=12.0.0.0

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013

My program makes use of visual basic power packs. While debugging, I encountered the 'DLL not found' exception and solved it by changing the copy local property of its reference to true. I've created setup of this program but when I try to run the installed program, (independent of VS 2013) its giving the same exception and I have no idea why or how to correct it. Any help would be great. Thanks in advance!!

My Error log shows this:

Exception:Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
GetType:System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Comment: Hmm, no, that is not something you have to do to debug your app.  But sure, you do when you build the Release version of your app and your installer needs to copy it as well.  The exception message says you did not do that.  Use Fuslogvw.exe to diagnose.

Comment: capture a WPR trace (http://stackoverflow.com/a/30289933/1466046) and expand the stack of the FileNotFoundException to see where in your code you get this exception

Comment: @HansPassant : What didn't I do? And how do I do it. I used Fuslogvw but its blank, and I'm pretty new to all this and kinda clueless at the moment.

Comment: capture the trace and look at it. It also includes the Fusion data (http://stackoverflow.com/a/29374658/1466046)