# C# ETW. How view call stack in PerfView?

Tags: c#, etw, perfview

Given

1. The implementation ETW provider (inherited from EventSource) with dynamic events. Provider name "IDS-IDComplete-DynamicTrace"
2. My implementation of Windows service, in which the events of ETW are generated
3. I collect events from the service using PerfVev:

`PerfView.exe collect ETWTrace.etl /merge /zip /OnlyProviders=*IDS-IDComplete-DynamicTrace`

4. I see all my events.

[image: PerfView with my events]

Question

How can I view the call stack in PerfVev so I can see the calls to my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have not captured callstacks. At commandline at the option @StacksEnabled set to true to capture callstacks: [/providers=YOUR_EVENTSOURCE@StacksEnabled=true](https://github.com/Microsoft/perfview/issues/159#issuecomment-281404358):

```
PerfView.exe collect ETWTrace.etl /merge /zip /Providers=*IDS-IDComplete-DynamicTrace@StacksEnabled=true
```

Comment: Is this a correct entry?

PerfView.exe collect ETWStacksEnabled.etl /merge /zip /OnlyProviders=*ITA-Dynamic-Trace:0x0004:Verbose:@StacksEnabled='true' "/StopOnPerfCounter=Processor:% Processor Time:_Total>60" /nogui /NoNGenRundown /DelayAfterTriggerSec=30

Comment: try it. I don't use perfview to capture a ETL. I use WPR with a self written profile: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30289933/1466046 Here I can better control what I capture