# Symbols not showing in Windows Performance Analyzer

Tags: c#, windows, profiling, debug-symbols, windows-performance-analyzer

I'm trying to use Windows Performance Analyzer to troubleshoot some performance issues in a WPF C# application. The application is built with .Net Framework 4.6.2. I am having the customer use UIForETW to record the traces.

The problem is that when I load symbols in WPA, I get all of the Microsoft symbols, but none of the symbols from my application. In the Thread Stack or New Thread Stack windows in WPA, I see a ?!? instead of what I think would be a ! from my application. Interestingly, I *do not* see the DLL name followed by  or anything like that. Only the ?!?

I do have a symbol server setup, and I can confirm that the version being run by the customer has the symbols stored in the symbol server. I do not get any errors loading symbols in WPA, and I can see that the symbols for my application and DLLs are present in the local symbols directory and in the WPA symbol cache.

It seems like everything is correct, but the symbols do not show up. Does anyone have any ideas as to why?

Thanks!

Comment: which windows/WPT version do you use? Also try WPR(UI).exe

Comment: I am using Windows Performance Analyzer 10.0.16299.15 on Windows 10. I've tried viewing captures that happened with the same software release on both Windows 7 and Windows 10.

Comment: open the ETL in [Perfview](https://github.com/Microsoft/perfview/releases/tag/P2.0.2) open the Events view and look if your trace includes **KERNELTRACECOntrol/ImageID/DbgID_RSDS** events. those events include the PDB information.

Comment: I opened the trace in Perfview. In the Events view, I do see DbgID_RSDS events for my process, but interestingly, I do not see any events that have pdb's for my exe or any of my DLL's. There are pdb's for things like the .Net Framework and some of the third party DLL's we use, but none of the DLL's that I built.

Comment: For Windows 7 you need the 10586 SDK/WPT, the original 10240 SDK had such symbol issues and later WPT no longer work on Win7. so make sure you use this special SDK/WPT version. also use WPR.exe directly, not this 3rd party tool to [capture traces with a wprp file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30289933/1466046)

Comment: Were you able to fix this problem?