# Visual Studio Diagnostic Tools. Failed to enable provider

Tags: visual-studio, debug-diagnostic-tool

I’m trying to get the Diagnostics Tools in Visual studio 2019 to work while having multiple instances of Visual studio running.

One is fine two works. Three or four, there is where the trouble starts.

Then I get
The diagnostic tool failed unexpectedly.

And in the output window.
Failed to enable provider {E13C0D23-CCBC-4E12-931B-D9CC2EEE27E4}: Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service.

My main question is, what system resources?
Is it not memory, I have 16Gb free. Not cpu, it is mainly ideling, and there is plenty of disk.

It does no matter if the other Visual studios are running a debug. Even if I just opened the solution and did nothing after that, they still seem to take up the “system resource”.

Does anyone have an idea of what system resource to get more of? Or is it some limitation / bug in the Diagnostic tools that cause this?

UPDATE
I gave up. Almost a year later and several updates of visual studio, the problem is still present and I have not found the source and have no clue why this keeps happening.

Comment: how many other ETW sessions are running on your box? Check it with **logman query -ets** Windows 10 has a limit of 64 concurrent ETW Sessions

Comment: At a quick count 25 plus 4 visual studio. so 29 total.

Comment: **{E13C0D23-CCBC-4E12-931B-D9CC2EEE27E4}** is the GUID for .net runtime ETW provider. Can you use [xperf/WPR to capture traces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30289933/1466046)? Does this work?

Comment: I am also facing such issue and everything I can do here is just to close other Visual Studio instances and that helps.